# how to show products and categories in magento 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, magento

i have installed the magento and new programmer to use magento 1.7.0.2.
ihave added two categories and two producs at backend bt nothing is showing at front page.
please any one can help me to show the products and categories on front page.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You often can check if a product is visible to the shop at all by visiting

```
http://yourshop.com/catalog/product/view/id/5
```

where 5 is the id of your product.
If you can see it go on and check the relation to the category, otherwise take a look at the visibility settings and status of your product.

Comment: i tried this but this link does not include the style sheets and how to show link on home page for category

Answer (score 1):

For Categories to show you must set `Is Active = Yes` also for `Include in Navigation Menu = Yes`, once categories are visible you can access products related to it but check if product are `enabled, Instock, Quantity assigned, related to categories`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Cateogories, select the specific category. - In General Informatiob tab find 'include in navigation' and 'is active', mark them 'yes'.

In next tab 'Display settings' find 'is Anchor', mark it yes as well.

Comment: i tried this but still getting blank home page. no any product or category displayed on home page

Comment: Blank page is something else.
Paste link to screenshot.

Comment: I am working on localhost that dosen't show any msg just show blank defualt page

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the category that you created are children category of the Default / Root category of Magento, i.e the category you created should have a category one level up and it should not be a root category by itself.